# Lua string.find correct format?

Tags: string, lua, string-matching, lua-patterns

I have quite simple question, but my google research did not help.. I am pretty new to Lua, so..

I have string "XXXX_YYYYYY_zzzzzz" stored in local variable and I want to parse it and get 3 new local variables. Should I use string.find?

```
local str_ = "XXXX_YYYYY_zzzzzz"    
local first_, second_, third_ = strind.find(str_, "^(%w+)_(%w+)_(%w+)$")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `string.match` instead:

```
local str_ = "XXXX_YYYYY_zzzzzz"    
local first_, second_, third_ = str_:match "^([^_]+)_([^_]+)_([^_]+)$"
```

Have a look at the [string library on lua-users wiki](http://lua-users.org/wiki/StringLibraryTutorial).

`string.find` would additionally return the indexes where the matched substring was located/found. These two (start and end) indices are not useful to your case, which is why `string.match` would be a better tool.

Comment: Instead of `%w+`, you can use `.-` just in case the fields contain punctuation.

Comment: @lhf I'd rather go with `[^_]`. Anyway, these speculations would depend on more input from OPs side.